# Remove ascii 0 from bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table and one of the entries is

EXTRA CHILI�����������

How can I remove those bad ascii 0 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select regexp_replace('EXTRA CHILI�����������', r'[[:^ascii:]]', '')
```

with output

[image]